# Unspecified running error while programing WeMos D1 in wireless mode

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi

I've tried to program `WeMos D1` directly by wireless connection. I've test my `D1` so it had no problem. after setting `SSID` and `Password` I've programed it for wireless using. It ran well. as I want to programing thought wireless there was an Unspecified error for running `python.exe` !

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at processing.app.helpers.ProcessUtils.exec(ProcessUtils.java:26)
    at cc.arduino.packages.Uploader.executeUploadCommand(Uploader.java:129)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.GenericNetworkUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(GenericNetworkUploader.java:99)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:78)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:709)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:682)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 8 more
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I've python on my PC  and it works. to clear my problem I've attached  the following `gif`

[image: the gif]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have Python installed, but can you run it?

Open a command window on you PC.  (Windows button R then CMD)
Then in that type python.

If python starts up then it should be working, but I suspect you will get an error saying:

`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

To fix this you need to edit you path and restart the IDE.  (How you edit you path depends on your version of Windows so you would be best searching for `edit environment path` and your version of windows and that should come back with an answer quickly.

Of course if its Linux/mac then it could still be the same issue.